# Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

Tags: mysql, centos, centos5

Im on CentOs v5.6 .When trying to start mysql im getting the following error

```
Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

In /var/log/mysqld.error.log i have the following

```
130319 03:39:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130319  3:39:04 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
130319  3:39:04 [Warning] '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--general_log'/'--general_log_file'' instead.
130319  3:39:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
130319  3:39:04 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130319  3:39:04  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130319  3:39:04  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130319  3:39:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
130319 03:39:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/ip-10-144-82-28.pid ended
```

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Post the command you're executing. It seems to have some deprecated options. Plus it seems mysqld is lacking some permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs it appears like file permission issue -

> "the error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the
>   directory"

Check ownership of var/lib/mysql directory:

```
ls -ld /var/lib/mysql
drwxr-xr-x 8 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 11 12:34 /var/lib/mysql
```

Output MUST show "mysql mysql" ownership and atleast "drwxr-xr-x" (755) permission

If permissions are not correct, grant it:

```
chown mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

Then,

Uninstall RPM (Only when it is fresh installation, and you do not have any mysql data. If it is not fresh installation, do a rpm -Uvh instead)
Remove all contents of /var/lib/mysql/ directory Re-install RPM
check if /var/lib/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm is created after installing RPM

Then give a service mysql start and watch logs.

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
>   130319  3:39:04 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

make sure all your "mysql" db files are in /var/lib/mysql/mysql/   ... or just run mysql_upgrade -p[password]

> 130319  3:39:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>   InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
>   InnoDB: the directory.
>   InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
>   InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.

as stated earlier, mysql cannot write to the /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 file.

make sure the user mysql is running as can write there.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Centos / RHEL or another distribution with selinux enabled that might be the culprit.

If that is the case disable selinux temporarily and see if it works.

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

If SElinux is the problem, then you should monitor audit.log and make it work (check: [MySQL 5.6 and SELinux are arguing](https://serverfault.com/questions/561914/mysql-5-6-and-selinux-are-arguing/))

You can also disable it permanently at **/etc/sysconfig/selinux** changing enforcing to either permissive or disabled.