# MySQL 5.6 and SELinux are arguing

Tags: mysql, selinux

CentOS 6.4(x64) / MySQL 5.6.10

Installed MySQL from source files and started it fine under it's original location (/var/lib/mysql). I moved everything to a different volume (/u0/mysql) and went through a few rounds of exempting it from SELinux (`cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mysql-*` followed by `semodule -i mysql-*.pp`). After every round of this I try to restart the service and see this error:

```
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file (/u0/mysql/server.pid).
 [FAILED]
```

After 3-4 rounds of adding exemptions I noticed that the files weren't changing anymore. IE everything that could be added this way had already been added. Out of curiosity I ran `audit2why -a` and got a slew of:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1387207317.009:666): avc:  <some permission> for  pid=20640 
  comm="mysqld" dev=sdc1 ino=36831373 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 
  tcontext=system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file
 Was caused by:
     Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
     Possible mismatch between this policy and the one under which the audit message was generated.
     Possible mismatch between current in-memory boolean settings vs. permanent ones.
```

This leads me to believe that it *should* be working. If I disable SELinux: `setenforce 0` then mysql will start just fine so it (SE) is still getting in the way.

Searching through SF turned [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/560869/unable-to-start-mysql-with-selinux) up - have tried it with no change in outcome.

SO: how do I find out where the blockage is?

EDIT:

```
[root@server u0]# ls -ldZ /var/lib/mysql
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 /var/lib/mysql

[root@server u0]# ls -ldZ /u0/mysql
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 /u0/mysql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the security context of the new directory to be the same as /var/lib/mysql.

For instance:

```
ls -ldZ /var/lib/mysql/
drwxr-x--x. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Then change the new directory to the same settings with chcon

```
chcon -R -u system_u -r object_r -t mysqld_db_t /u0/mysql
```

Comment: Just did this. No change in outcome.

Comment: What's the output of ls -ldZ /var/lib/mysql and /u0/mysql?

Comment: Try to reload the policy: semodule -R and then audit2why since last reload: audit2why -l to see if anything shows.

Comment: No change. `audit2why -l` has no output.

Comment: What is mysql error log? You can try to enable logging of the don't audits at semodule using: semodule -B -D. There should be a lot more things in the audit log, see if anything relates.

Comment: There isn't just a single mysql context to consider. Log files, configuration files and so on got their own contexts. Give a look at the output of "semanage fcontext --list |grep mysql"

Comment: Using `semodule -B -D` seems to have kicked something loose again. Now I'm able to use `audit2allow` to create exemptions again. This seems to be working. TY.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this:

```
chcon --reference=/path/to/existing/file /path/to/new/file
```

BTW, here is a great intro to SELinux: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxjenQ31b70 from Redhat 2012 Summit. Also, look in your log files for error messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: There are no new entries in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` once I've added the pre-existing exemptions.